# Redactor - can't link to files

Tags: redactor

I have added the "file" option in my Standard.json file for Redactor.
Wehn using the Redactor field then I can click on the file button and select the image ok.
When I view source the file is linked to fine in the html.
But when I save the entry and go back to view it - the link is stripped out - it just displays:

```
<a>link text</a>
```

I have tried disabling Clean Up HTML and Purify HTML on the field options and saving again but still have the same problem - the link is being stripped out.

Anyone have a similiar issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just had this problem. Are you using AWS for your files?

If yes, check your Asset Source "Base URL" does not start with `//` otherwise the file link in redactor will start with `https:////` and break (resulting in null). I simply changed this to https:// and Redactor was happy.

Hope that helps.

Comment: No the files were local - but I had the base url beginning with `\\`. Changed as you suggested and the issue is resolved.